# What is the Big O complexity of the following piece of code?

Tags: python, big-o, complexity-theory

Is the complexity O(n^2)?

```
def f(n):
    def g(m):
        m = 0
        for i in range(m):
            print(m)
    for i in range(n):
        g(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner function sets `m=0`, making it constant time. So the whole thing is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

No, the Big O complexity is simply O(n), as, within `g`, you throw away the given value of `m` and set it to zero, so the loop in `g` runs for zero iterations.